# SELECT 1 FROM [SystemEventLog]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I do have an SQL Job that executes a stored procedure daily `8:00 AM`.

In stored, there is a statement :

```
    DECLARE @midnight datetime,
    @startTime datetime = GETUTCDATE();

    -- Has this stored procedure already run for today?
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [SystemEventLog] WHERE [CreatedDateTime_UTC] >= CAST(@midnight AS DATE) AND [CreatedDateTime_UTC] < DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(@midnight AS DATE)))
    BEGIN
         RETURN
    END


-- log that this storedproc ran
DECLARE @SystemEventLogId int 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SystemEventLog] ( [EventType_Id], [StoredProcName], [Details] )
VALUES( 1, 'StoredProcedureOne', null )
```

According to the comment, this block is checking that whether this store procedure has run today or not, if yes then return.

But I am not getting how does it checks whether this procedure has alreday ran today or not?

Can anyone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: As you are not giving the full text of the SP, one can only guess. My guess is that a record is written by the stored procedure (or something that it calls) to `[SystemEventLog]` when it executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking that stored procedure down ...

```
SELECT 1 FROM [SystemEventLog]
    WHERE [CreatedDateTime_UTC] >= CAST(@midnight AS DATE)
      AND [CreatedDateTime_UTC] < DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(@midnight AS DATE))
```

This will output a single row (the `1` is irrelevant - it's just content) if that condition is met.

Then ...

```
IF EXISTS ( [statement] )
```

is true if `[statement]` returns at least one row. If it is true, the stored procedure exits (through the `RETURN` statement); if false, it will continue.

The part missing from your example would be below this, where it will then add a new line to `SystemEventLog` that will - on later executions - then make the condition `true` for the rest of the day.

Comment: OK. But how you can judge that this will return 1 for only this specific stored Procedure? There can be more than one SQL Jobs running for today and they are calling the different Stored Procedures as well. So there might be entries in [SystemEventLog] for today. In that case, if my stored procedure has not ran than also it will return true?

Comment: You are very true that I have missed the part in which there are statement inserting value with name and current date of stored procedure's execution, but I am not getting that how does an SQL query will judge to return true for this Stored-Procedure only, not for the other stored procedure?

Comment: @Dev There's nothing in that query to narrow it down to just your stored procedure, but answering this new part would require more information - do those other procedures write to this table, for example? Do they definitely all run if they do?

Comment: I have updated the code block with insert statement I am using in that SP after the check.

Comment: @Dev I'd be interested to see the content of that table, but these comments are expanding on the original question a bit. However, a few questions come to mind - 1) Do all the other procedures have this same insert in? 2) Is the check at the top the same? 3) Do they all actually run?